# Saving Variable and retrieving later

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I am trying to save the variable in python which will create a text file. Am i going wrong? I want to know where the file would be created/
Here is the code:

```
import pickle as pk
f = open("featuresvmt.txt", "w")
pk.dump(feature_svmt, f)
pk.dump(out_val, f)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

- The file should be opened in *binary* writing mode: `f = open("featuresvmt.txt", "wb")`.
- The file `featuresvmt.txt` will be created in the current working directory. You can find the current working directory using `os.getcwd()`. Or, simply supply an absolute path: `f = open("/path/to/featuresvmt.txt", "wb")`.

---

```
import pickle as pk
feature_svmt, out_val = 'foo', 12.34

with open("featuresvmt.txt", "wb") as f:
    pk.dump(feature_svmt, f)
    pk.dump(out_val, f)

with open("featuresvmt.txt", "rb") as f:
    print(pk.load(f))
    # foo
    print(pk.load(f))
    # 12.34
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can run and create a file where you run iPython. (Of course you must initialized both of used variable)
If you run iPython from terminal or command prompt, which directory is your actual path will contain the new file.